# Mongodb consultar e retornar elementos especificos de array dentro de objetos

Tags: json, query, mongodb, filter

Galera, to precisando de um help para consultar determinados valores em um documento.

Tenho uma coleção no mongo que segue essa estrutura, inclusive esse é o documento que eu consigo e preciso localizar: https://github.com/pedrualves/document/blob/master/school.js

O find esta tranquilo eu encontro documento sem problemas usando o criterio: "pages": 32

O problema que tenho é para exibir apenas os items de array que estão em objetos, da seguinte maneira, é o que eu espero retornar da consulta por "pages": 32 :

```
{
"book": [
 {
  "pages": 32,
  "title": "a"
 },
 {
  "pages": 32,
  "title": "c"
 },
 {
  "pages": 32,
  "title": "d"
 }
]
}
```

será que alguém pode me dar o caminho das pedras, dicas ou sugestões???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o Unwind do aggregate para fazer a quebra do array assim voce pode agrupar e filtrar.

```
db.'collection_name'.aggregate([
{ $unwind : "$students" },
{ $unwind : "$students.class" },
{ $unwind : "$students.class.book" },
{$match:{"students.class.book.pages":{$in:[32]}}},
{$group:
{
_id:'$students.name',
teste:{$push:'$students.class.book'}
}
}
])
```

Também pode ser usado o $redact